# ¿Cómo puedo leer un dato especifico dentro de un campo en un tabla mysql json usando php?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

Mi base de datos en mysql tiene una tabla llamada "ventas" donde hay un campo "productos" donde esta grabado unos datos en json y dentro de este json solo necesito sacar la información "marca" para poder mostrarlo en un datatable, Gracias.

1.- Base de Datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function mostrarTablaSell(){

        $item = null;
        $valor = null;
        $orden = "id";

        $ventas = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarVentas($item, $valor, $orden);   

        if(count($ventas) == 0){

            echo '{"data": []}';

            return;
        }

        $datosJson = '{
          "data": [';

          for($i = 0; $i < count($ventas); $i++){

                    $here = json_decode($ventas[$i]["productos"], true);

                    //$marca = $here['marca'];
                    //$marca = $here[2]->'marca';
                    $marca = $here[1];  

            $datosJson .='[

                  "'.($i+1).'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["id"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["id_vendedor"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["id_cliente"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["proviene"].'",
                  "'.$marca.'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["desp"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["adelanto"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["total"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["estado"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["obs"].'",
                  "'.$ventas[$i]["fecha"].'",
                  "'.$botones.'"
                ],';

          }

          $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);

         $datosJson .=   '] 

         }';

        echo $datosJson;


    }
```

Comment: sigo sin entenderlo. Por que la gente se complica a definir el json en lugar de utilizar las funciones en php que hay para ello. Tienes `json_encode()` y `json_decode()` entre las funciones de PHP, te simplificaria muchas cosas... En este caso ademas mezclas definir un json con dichas funciones.

Comment: viendo tu tabla, el campo `productos` es un array de objetos, que tiene un unico objeto. Por lo tanto, despues de `$here = json_decode(...)` dentro de $here tienes un elemento, que es un objeto. Por ello, `$marca = $here[0]['marca']` debe devolverte el campo marca.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu tabla, el campo PRODUCTOS es un json, que decodificado es un ARRAY de objetos con UN único elemento. Por tanto, tu código debería buscar el elemento con indices `0` y `marca`. Algo como:

```
$marca = $here[0]['marca'];
```

Cambiaria el codigo que tienes por algo como lo siguiente:

```
public function mostrarTablaSell(){
    $item = null;
    $valor = null;
    $orden = "id";

    $ventas = ControladorVentas::ctrMostrarVentas($item, $valor, $orden);   
    if(count($ventas) == 0){
        echo json_encode(['data' => []);
        return;
    }

    $datosjson = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($ventas); $i++){
        $here = json_decode($ventas[$i]["productos"], true);
        $marca = $here[0]['marca'];
```

...

Comment: Gracias, hermano!!!!

Comment: Pero... ¿por qué recorrer todos los elementos para guardar solamente uno? ¿No te parece poco óptimo ese proceder? Considero que @AllegroCanttabile debe plantearse un cambio en la lógica del programa.

Comment: coincido con @A.Cedano. AL final recorres todos los elementos para cojer uno que esta en un campo json... Creo recordar que es posible hacer una consulta que te devuelva en ese campo en concreto uno de los valores del json con `JSON_EXTRACT(productos, '$.marca')`. Con ello te quitarias mucho lio...